# Firebase like counter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm confused here and really at the end on the line, I have set up a like function in my project. if a user presses the like button once, the like counter update from 0 to 1(liked) and the like imageButton(change color) updates successful. if pressed twice the counter updates from 1 to 0(unlike) successful.

The problem is when a different user also press the like button to like the same post, the like counter does not update from 1 to 2. Please help. I hope this is clear. Below is the code.

```
viewHolder.mLikebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mProcessLike = true;
        mDatabaseLikeCount =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child(post_key).child("likecount");

        mDatabaseLikeCount.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mProcessLike) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                        Log.i("D Diary", "User has already Liked. So it can be considered as Unliked.");
                        mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                        mDatabaseLikeCount.setValue(likeCount = likeCount - 1 );
                        mProcessLike = false;
                    } else {
                        Log.i("D Diary", "User Liked");
                        mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(auth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
                        mDatabaseLikeCount.setValue(likeCount = likeCount + 1 );
                        Log.i(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "Count");
                        mProcessLike = false;
                    }
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         });
     }
 });
```

Comment: Can you show, how you define the likeCount variable?

Comment: in POJO it is initialized at 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You should use a transaction to increment or reduce a value that multiple people will be interacting with.

```
if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
    Log.i("D Diary", "User has already Liked. So it can be considered as Unliked.");
    mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
    updateCounter(false);
    mProcessLike = false;
} else {
    Log.i("D Diary", "User Liked");
    mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(auth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
    updateCounter(true)
    Log.i(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "Count");
    mProcessLike = false;
}
```

With updateCounter:

```
private void updateCounter(bool increment) {
    mDatabaseLikeCount.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            if (mutableData.getValue() != null) {
                int value = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                if(increment) {
                    value++;
                } else {
                    value--;
                }
                mutableData.setValue(value);
            }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "likeTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

[Firebase Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

Comment: can you please help me on where to put my update counter?

Comment: Just anywhere in the same class as the code you posted.

Comment: not its not working, if (value != null) it gives an error saying operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'int', 'null' and when i change from if (value != null) to if (value != 0) and run the app, counter is not updating anymore. even for one user

Comment: Try `(mutableData.getValue() != null)` and put the `int value = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);` inside of your if statement, I'll edit it in the answer.

Comment: I'v realized that when i put  if (value != null) to if (value != 0) and in my firebase likecount database i initialize counts from 0 to 1 it works perfect. problem now is that count needs to start from 0 not 1. thank you this has been veryhelpful

Comment: thank you so much after adding (mutableData.getValue() != null) it worked.